# Node base64 encode doesn't give whole string

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, tostring

Good day,

I am having a weird issue with Node, I am encoding a file as Base64 and albeit it works for most of my PDFs that I am encoding, one in particular doesn't output the whole base64 string.

The actual b64 string starts like this: `"JVBERi0xLjMKJf////8KNiAwIG9i..."` but I only get `"JVBERi0xLjMK"`

Here is my code:

```
function sendPDF() {
    // Grab the final PDF
    require('fs').readFile(transaction.deliverable, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            log(2, "Couldn't read: " + transaction.deliverable);
        } else {
            transaction.deliverable = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('base64');
            //transaction.deliverable = data.toString('base64');
            console.log(transaction.deliverable);

}
```

The commented out line was another attempt. The transaction structure is:

```
function Transaction(snapshot) {
    var data         = snapshot.val();
    this.tid         = snapshot.key();
    this.request     = data.request;
    this.pages       = [];
    this.fileCount   = 0;
    this.deliverable = null;
    this.fileName    = "";
}
```

This transaction simple stores some information that I pull from Firebase however the important var, `.deliverable` is a string to the path of the PDF I need to encode and send.

I don't get any read errors when this happens, and the next transaction goes through this code block just fine, giving a full base64 string.

I was curious if my `toString()` was interpolating the base64 string, but then I thought I would have had larger problems earlier.

Any ideas? I can put this on hold and move on with my work but I would love to fix this.. Thank you.

Comment: Is your input data really binary? `new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('base64')`

Comment: From what I can tell it should be. Here is a link to the file I am encoding: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45190281/JlY6AjM6fwMj3fBNF6W-1.pdf

Comment: Funny that it truncated at the location where a pair of forward slashes exist...

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I couldn't find anything on how `toString()` interpolates and also it is truncated 2 characters before the double pair of forward slashes :\

Comment: Could you possibly be running into memory constraints? I just tried to reproduce your problem and I actual do get the full encoded string for that PDF. Maybe try redownloading the PDF or testing it in a different environment.

Comment: Perhaps.. I will give it a try on our VPS once I get a chance.